# Highlight a cell if any other in a range has a future date

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm wanting to highlight one particular cell in the header, as a visible indicator that there are future dates in the sheet, that might be out of sight. The data usual contains 400 rows of data

One of the header calls contains today's date (`=TODAY()`) and is used in conditional formatting formulas to highlight rows that match other criteria as well and might have a future date. This cell (L1) is the one I want to mark a different colour if there is a row with a future date.

The data is however not always containing future dates. Hence I want an indicator that warns if there is a row that contains a future date (dates are in column D).

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

The data looks like this:
[image]

Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please select L1 HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF(D:D,">"&L$1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, OK, OK.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately when I tried that it did not deliver the expected result. The 'COUNTIF(D:D,">"&$L$1)' returns 0 while there are two dates that exceed the current date.

Comment: Same issue, still no hit

Comment: Your suspicion was right :) it is a text field 30/11/2015 converted to 42338, etc. Changing the range to M:M then results in a positive match of the two dates that I see in the example.

Comment: I had to modify it to get it to actually change the colour in the conditional formatting step. This is the modified formula: 'COUNTIF(M:M,">"&VALUE($L$1))'